# Part of Q icon in leftnav disappeared on mouse hover

Tags: bug, design, left-nav

When you hover a Question item on left-nav by mouse the bottom left corner of the icon disappears:

> [image]

Animation below (tested on Windows 11 Google Chrome):

> [image]

Comment: I'd never have noticed it, as my icons are about half the size of the ones pictured here, but you're right.

Comment: @Tetsujin I zoomed them for better visibility

Comment: Also happens on Chrome v.118 on OS X (Catalina), so not Windows only.